# Python Pandas DataFrame: Rename all Column Names via Map

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that I can rename all DataFrame columns to lowercase via:

```
df_from_csv.columns = map(str.lower, df_from_csv.columns)
```

If I try to change all spaces in the DataFrame to underscore, I get an error:

```
>> df_from_csv.columns = map(str.replace(" ", "_"), df_from_csv.columns)

TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How does the correct syntax look like?

Comment: You can directly do `df.columns = df.columsn.str.replace(" ","_")`

Comment: df_from_csv.columns=df_from_csv.columns.str.replace(" ", "_"), will do